# Load embedded xml in xamarin (c#)

Tags: android, xml, mono, load, xamarin

I'm new to android/xamarin.
I have an embedded xml file that I want to read in "Resources\xml\settings.xml" but I can't open it with the XmlDocument();

Can anyone help me correct this code?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.Load ("Resources\xml\settings.xml");
int c = 0;
foreach (XmlNode item in doc.ChildNodes) {
    name[c] = item.ChildNodes [0].InnerText;
    pref[c] =  item.ChildNodes [1].InnerText;
    c++;
}
```

It always gives me an error in the "doc.load(..." line and I've tried everything.
(Build action is set to embeddedResource)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a Resoure, add the file as an [Asset](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/).

```
string content;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (Assets.Open ("settings.xml")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.LoadXml (content);
```

Comment: Well, I think that's as easy as it seems. At least now I have the entire Xml inside the string, but when I debug your last line of code it throws an exception. I think the app is trying to read a file named "the entire Xml data". What could be the problem? Should I use another solution to get my 2 arrays populated?

Comment: Error is shown as The name 'Assets' does not exist in the current context.